# How can I combine two URLSearchParams in Angular/TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two `URLSearchParams` objects, and I want to make a third one of those two combined.

For example, I could have

```
let params1 = new URLSearchParams();
params1.set('page', 'one');
params1.set('size', 'hundred');

let params2 = new URLSearchParams();
params2.set('orderBy', 'size');
params2.set('order', 'asc');

let params = params1 + params2; // yes, that's illegal, but how to do that?
```

and I need to have all 4 parameters in the params object.

I wanted to iterate through the object key-value pairs using [.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/entries) method, but TypeScript hides this method. Here is what I've found in `lib.dom.d.ts` file:

```
interface URLSearchParams {
    append(name: string, value: string): void;
    delete(name: string): void;
    get(name: string): string | null;
    getAll(name: string): string[];
    has(name: string): boolean;
    set(name: string, value: string): void;
}

declare var URLSearchParams: {
    prototype: URLSearchParams;
    new (init?: string | URLSearchParams): URLSearchParams;
};
```

So it looks like there's no possible option to iterate through `URLSearchParams` in TS. Any ideas?

Comment: by combine what you exactly mean. give an example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `appendAll()` method see [**Docs**](https://angular.io/api/http/URLSearchParams#appendAll) as below,

```js
let params1 = new URLSearchParams();
params1.set('page', 'one');
params1.set('size', 'hundred');

let params2 = new URLSearchParams();
params2.set('orderBy', 'size');
params2.set('order', 'asc');

let params = new URLSearchParams();
params.appendAll(params1);
params.appendAll(params2);
console.log(params);
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/ARIAGUkzpRYu6Er4yuV7?p=preview)**

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly. I haven't imported `URLSearchParams` from `@angular/http` previously, that's why the definition was taken from `lib.dom.d.ts`.

Answer (score 23):

Since the accepted solution was specific to Angular, here is one that will work with vanilla JS:

```js
let params1 = new URLSearchParams();
params1.set('page', 'one');
params1.set('size', 'hundred');

let params2 = new URLSearchParams();
params2.set('page', 'two');
params2.set('orderBy', 'size');
params2.set('order', 'asc');

let combined = new URLSearchParams({
  ...Object.fromEntries(params1),
  ...Object.fromEntries(params2)
});

console.log(combined.toString());
// page=two&size=hundred&orderBy=size&order=asc
```

Comment: This doesn't handle the case where you have repeated keys.

Comment: @LiauJianJie I guess that depends on how you define "handling". There isn't a consensus on how server-side applications should handle repeat parameters because it is not defined in any RFC, so there are several different behaviors. Some keep the first occurrence, some keep the last occurrence, some create an array, and some create a delimited list of all parameters, so it really depends on what you are using on the server whether this solution would work or not. In this code, one value is overwritten by the other. That would probably work in the majority of cases.

Comment: @LiauJianJie With that said, you might want to ask yourself if you really want to allow your application to create duplicate query parameters. That sounds like bad code smell to me. Allowing your application to behave differently depending on the order of duplicate query parameters seems error-prone and who's to say that the client wouldn't somehow switch the order or drop one of the parameters, or that future versions of the server software wouldn't behave differently?

Comment: IIRC, PHP will read multiple parameters of the same name to an array if the name ends with `[]`. So if you're interfacing with a PHP backend, that case might be useful handling.

Comment: arrays are often captured with "duplicate" query strings e.g. `id[]=123&id[]=567`.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you've worked out it was a definition issue, here are some answers to your other dilemmas.

> let params = params1 + params2; // yes, that's illegal, but how to do that?

URLSearchParams get converted into a query string via toString().

```
let params = params1.toString() + params2.toString();
```

NB: URLSearchParams create a search query where arrays are converted equivalent to array.toString() eg: `q=x%2Cy%2Cz`, differing from **querystring.stringify()** output which maps the key to each value in an array, eg `q=x&q=y&q=z`. This is something to be aware of if you're merging URLSearchParams via append/appendAll, and have duplicate keys.

To have duplicate keys, behaving more like querystring, create using iterators.

```
let params = new URLSearchParams([
    ['page', 'one'],
    ['size', 'hundred'],
    ['orderBy', 'size'],
    ['order', 'asc']
]);
```

Alternatively, `params.forEach((value, name[, searchParams]) => {})` is also available to iterate.

Manually setting each key-value misses one of the best features of this constructor - it's parsing capabilities! Any leading `?` is ignored from strings great for appending params to a url query string.

```
let params1 = new URLSearchParams(('?page=one&size=hundred');
let params2 = new URLSearchParams({
    orderBy: 'size',
    order: 'asc'
});
```