# Combine two URLSearchParams()

Tags: javascript

Quick question:

Is it possible to combine two instances of `URLSearchParams`?

```
const params1 = new URLSearchParams();
const params2 = new URLSearchParams();

const finalParms = mergeThis(params1, params2) <- do this?
```

This question has been answered for [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45126076/how-can-i-combine-two-urlsearchparams-in-angular-typescript) but in plain JavaScript `URLSearchParams` has no member called `.appendAll()`

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's no built-in method to do that, but you can simply loop over the entries and append them:

```js
const params1 = new URLSearchParams("?foo=foo&bar=bar");
const params2 = new URLSearchParams("?baz=baz&nii=nii");
for (let [key, val] of params2.entries()) {
  params1.append(key, val);
}
console.log(params1.toString());
```

Comment: Ok, awesome. This is super helpful. Also, I think an answer to this question needed to exist on SO so people can find it in the future.

Comment: If I understand URLSearchParams correctly, this will mean that any duplicate keys will be doubled up, eg the same key exists in both, then the resulting one will have the same key twice.  I am in the situation where I have to let keys in one override the other, and therefore needed to convert to an object and then back to a URLSearchParams.

Comment: @thomasrutter — Then use `set` instead of `append`. No need for an extra object.

Comment: You're right.  I don't know why I had written that.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can make one with `URLSearchParams.append()`:

```js
function combineSearchParams(searchParams1, searchParams2) {
  const result = new URLSearchParams("");

  // Display the key/value pairs
  [searchParams1, searchParams2].map(params => {
    for(var pair of params.entries()) {
      result.append(pair[0], pair[1]);
    }
  });

  return result;
}
```

Then you can:

```
const searchParams1 =
  new URLSearchParams("key1=value1&key2=value2");
const searchParams2 =
  new URLSearchParams("key3=value3&key4=value4");

const combined =
 combineSearchParams(searchParams1, searchParams2);

// "key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3&key4=value4"
console.log(combined.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining the two in a template works well as `toString()` is called on each implicitly.

```js
const a = new URLSearchParams({ a: 1 })
const b = new URLSearchParams({ b: 2 })

const finalParms = `${a}&${b}` // 'a=1&b=2'
```

You could also make a simple util to do this like

```js
const mergeParams = (...params) => params.map(String).join('&')
const finalParms = mergeParams(a, b) // 'a=1&b=2'
```

Comment: If `a` is an empty search params (`new URLSearchParams({ })`) you will get `&b=2` which is not a valid search params